# Django: MySQL syntax error when passing parameters to raw SQL query

Tags: mysql, django

I'm trying to perform a raw SQL query, like so

```
test = Poll.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM %s', ['polls_poll'])
```

and it results in an error:

```
ProgrammingError at ...

(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax...
```

Debug Toolbar shows that Django performs the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM 'polls_poll'
```

If I execute this query directly in the MySQL shell, it won't work either, unless I replace single quotes (') with backticks (`).

How do I make Django use backticks? Or what am I doing wrong?

Environment: Django 1.6, MySQL 5.6.14, OS X 10.9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can only pass query *parameters*, not *field names*, so it will not work for table names.

Alternatively, you can try simple string building for your query:

```
test_query = 'SELECT * FROM %s' % 'polls_poll'
test = Poll.objects.raw(test_query)
```

Although, string formatting for raw queries is not recommended.

More information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. `global name 'polls_poll' is not defined`

Comment: Thanks, I have improved my answer!